# Windows Batch File Conversion with Retained Audio Metadata using FFmpeg Error

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, batch, metadata

I'm fairly new to using this program, and really programming of any kind, but after tooling around on the internet (a lot of this site actually), I managed to come up with this.

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR %%AA IN (*.flac) DO (
echo Converting: %%AA
ffmpeg -i "%%AA" -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 "%%~nf.mp3"
)

echo Finished

PAUSE
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I run the program I get the error "At least one output file must be specified".  When I remove the -map_metadata 0 command, the program works fine, but no metadata is saved in the mp3 file.  Does anyone know what's going wrong with this program, or what I can chnage to fix it?

EDIT: Now correctly displays my code.

Comment: if you add `echo ` in front of the `ffmpeg`  what do you see?

Comment: Converting: %AA
ffmpeg -i "%AA" -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 "test.mp3"

Comment: This seems to be an ffmpeg error so double check your syntax and confirm you can run with a single file first... report back your results..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace the `%%AA` with `%%f`:

**Code:**

```
@echo off
FOR %%f IN (*.flac) DO (
echo Converting: %%f
ffmpeg -i "%%f" -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 "%%~nf.mp3"
)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.  I don't actually know why my code appeared like that in my post here, I originally had all of the lines as %%AA in my batch file.

Comment: redo the `echo` experiment and make sure the echo command line looks like what you expect it to.  Also you should edit your post to look like reality.

Comment: Converting: Test 1.flac
ffmpeg -i "Test 1.flac" -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 "Test 1.mp3" This is right as far as I can tell

Comment: If you cut and paste the second echo output to the command line, do you get the same result?

Comment: Yes, I still get the same error.

Comment: So this appears to be a command line issue, not a batch issue.  So at the command line, try it again with a file with no spaces in the name, it might be some sort of quoting issue.  GL.